# How to target input text box using Selenium (for Java) if type of element is <object></object>

Tags: java, selenium, element, activex, ocx

I'm trying to login onto a particular site with Selenium, however,  I cannot directly reference the password input due to this type of html element. The code below is actually a input text element.

```
<object tabindex="2" class="ocx_style" id="ocx_passwordChar_login" classid="CLSID:123ABCD-34AC-CY23-ABC1-6423F8C40100" codebase="/ocx/APPIE32.cab#version=1,0,0,1" onkeydown="authenticateUser();">
 <param name="maxlength" value="20"/>
```

(I just provided dummy values on the attribute, but the format is the same)

It seems that this is an activeX form. I tried using the normal `passwd.findElementById("ocx_passwordChar_login");` but it didn't work.

What other possible ways to directly get focus on the text box and be able to send keys on it? I want also to be able to check if it has a value once you have reference on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with different alternatives like:
Use CSS Selector

```
WebElement someElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ocx_style"));
```

OR,
Simply press TAB after you entered userName

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Xpath of UserName"));
webElement.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

Comment: The first solution doesn't work. It will just get focused on the input password field but not typing anything. The latter solution is currently implemented thru the use of Robot from java.awt then used custom typing mechanism that simulate the input from actual keyboard. The problem is that we're not able to check the contents of that password field, even using `webElement.getAttribute("value")` returns null. I was looking if there exist other solution aside from the stated above. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Can you please try this: inputField = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('gbqfq'));
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '" + longstring +"')", inputField);

Comment: by the way this doesn't still work. The website uses some activeX extensions that prevents selenium to work on that site.